# How to compare two variable and different length data frames to add values from one data frame to the other, repeating values where necessary

Tags: r, dataframe

I apologize as I'm not sure how to word this title exactly.

I have two data frames. df1 is a series of paths with columns "source" and "destination". df2 stores values associated with the destinations. Below is some sample data:

### df1

| row | source | destination |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | B |
| 2 | C | B |
| 3 | H | F |
| 4 | G | B |

### df2

| row | destination | n |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | B | 26 |
| 2 | F | 44 |
| 3 | L | 12 |

I would like to compare the two data frames and add the n column to df1 so that df1 has the correct n value for each destination. df1 should look like:

| row | source | destination | n |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | B | 26 |
| 2 | C | B | 26 |
| 3 | H | F | 44 |
| 4 | G | B | 26 |

The data that I'm actually working with is much larger, and is never the same number of rows when I run the program. The furthest I've gotten with this is using the `which` command to get the right values, but only each value once.

```
df2[ which(df2$destination %in% df1$destination), ]$n

[1] 26 44
```

When what I would need is the list (26,26,44,26) so I can save it to `df1$n`

Comment: `merge(df1, df2, by = "destination")`

Answer (score 1):

We can use a `merge` or `left_join`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[df2, n := i.n, on = .(destination)]
```

Answer (score 0):

A base R option using `match`

```
transform(
  df1,
  n = df2$n[match(destination, df2$destination)]
)
```

which gives

```
  row source destination  n
1   1      A           B 26
2   2      C           B 26
3   3      H           F 44
4   4      G           B 26
```

**Data**

```
df1 <- data.frame(row = 1:4, source = c("A", "C", "H", "G"), destination = c("B", "B", "F", "B"))
df2 <- data.frame(row = 1:3, destination = c("B", "F", "L"), n = c(26, 44, 12))
```